# How would you re-write this jQuery code into ES6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

The idea is to get all the links and responding IDs, hide content that is not 'active'. When clicked, the anchor link should open is corresponding content.

#### The Markup

```
<div class="navbar">
  <nav>
    <ul class="navTabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#tab1">
          Tab 1
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab2">
          Tab 2
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab3">
          Tab 3
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="navcontent">
  <div class="content" id="tab1">
    <h4>
      Tab 1
    </h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="tab2">
    <h4>
      Tab 2
    </h4>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="tab3">
    <h4>
      Tab 3
    </h4>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### The script

```
$('ul.navTabs').each(function() {
  var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

  $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
  $active.addClass('active');

  $content = $($active[0].hash);

  $links.not($active).each(function() {
    $(this.hash).hide();
  });

  $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $active.removeClass('active');
    $content.hide();

    $active = $(this);
    $content = $(this.hash);

    $active.addClass('active');
    $content.show();
  });

});
```

The above script code works and the challenge is to re-write that into ES6 (which I have done below but doesn't work as expected). [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ostoh/vnx7cesa/) is a jsFiddle code to illustrate the issue that I am facing.

```
$("ul.navTabs > li").each((index, element) => {
  // keep track of tabs and associated content
  const anchorTag = $(element).find("a");
  let active = anchorTag;
  let content = anchorTag;
  const links = anchorTag;

  // if identifyUrlHash matches one of the links, use that as active tab
  // if no match found, use first link as initial active tab
  const identifyUrlHash = window.location.hash;
  active = $(links.filter(`[href="${identifyUrlHash}"]`)[0] || links[0]);
  active.addClass("active");

  content = $(active[0].hash);

  // hide the remaining content
  links.not(active).each(element, (subindex, subelement) => {
    $(subelement.hash).hide();
  });

  $(element).on("click", "a", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // old tab inactive
    active.removeClass("active");
    content.hide();

    // update variables with new link and content
    active = $(element);
    content = $(element.hash);

    // make tab active
    element.addClass("active");
    content.show();
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the question? What does not work in the code you posted?

Comment: What does this have to do with ES6 specifically? Do you have working code in ES5?

Comment: @Bergi Please have a look at the jsFiddle code to see the issue I have.

Comment: Do you actually even care about ES5 vs ES6?

Comment: No, please describe the issue. What does not work as expected?

Comment: @Bergi Added more details, hope it's a little clearer

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "in ES6"? You just want to use arrow functions? What are you trying to accomplish? Define "doesn't work".

Comment: @DaveNewton As per the question, how do I ensure both 'each' functions work in tandem and in the right way (re-written to ES6). The jsfiddle code gives an idea of the bug.

Comment: Questions need to stand on their own. Describe the behavior vs desired behavior.

Comment: I can only see that in the rewrite you changed `$active.addClass('active');` to `element.addClass("active");` for some reason, but `element` is not a jQuery collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use class `.active` on both links and panes.
- Don't style LI elements. Use `active` in the A elements
- Use JS's [`classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) method (or [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) in jQuery)

## jQuery

```js
const $tabs = $(".navbar a");
const $panes = $(".navcontent .content");

const handlePanes = (ev) => {
  const hash = ev ? ev.currentTarget.hash : window.location.hash;
  if (!hash) return; // No hash, use inline "active" classes
  $tabs.each((i, el) => $(el).toggleClass("active", el.hash === hash));
  $panes.each((i, el) => $(el).toggleClass("active", el.id === hash.replace("#", "")));
}

$tabs.on("click", handlePanes);
handlePanes(); // On init, page load, read hash (if any) and make active
```

```css
.navbar nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* PS don't overstyle LI elements treat them like you would TD elements */

.navbar nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.navbar nav a.active { /* style inner elements instead */
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

/* PANES STYLES */
.navcontent .content {
  display: none;
}
.navcontent .content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <nav>
    <ul class="navTabs">
      <li>
        <a href="#tab1" class="active">
          Tab 1
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab2">
          Tab 2
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab3">
          Tab 3
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="navcontent">
  <div class="content active" id="tab1">
    <h4>
      Tab 1
    </h4>
    <p>11111 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="tab2">
    <h4>
      Tab 2
    </h4>
    <p>
      22222 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="tab3">
    <h4>
      Tab 3
    </h4>
    <p>
      33333 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

## JavaScript (no jQuery)

```js
const ELS_tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar a");
const ELS_panes = document.querySelectorAll(".navcontent .content");

const handlePanes = (ev) => {
  const hash = ev ? ev.currentTarget.hash : window.location.hash;
  if (!hash) return; // No hash, use inline "active" classes
  ELS_tabs.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle("active", el.hash === hash));
  ELS_panes.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle("active", el.id === hash.replace("#", "")));
}

ELS_tabs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", handlePanes));
handlePanes(); // On init, page load, read hash (if any) and make active
```

```css
.navbar nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* PS don't overstyle LI elements treat them like you would TD elements */

.navbar nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.navbar nav a.active { /* style inner elements instead */
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

/* PANES STYLES */
.navcontent .content {
  display: none;
}
.navcontent .content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <nav>
    <ul class="navTabs">
      <li>
        <a href="#tab1" class="active">
          Tab 1
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab2">
          Tab 2
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab3">
          Tab 3
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="navcontent">
  <div class="content active" id="tab1">
    <h4>
      Tab 1
    </h4>
    <p>11111 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="tab2">
    <h4>
      Tab 2
    </h4>
    <p>
      22222 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="tab3">
    <h4>
      Tab 3
    </h4>
    <p>
      33333 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need JQ?

Comment: @NjugunaMureithi it was a leftover. Removed

Comment: Why did you rewrite the code from jQuery to DOM methods? That's not what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @Bergi hum ham, got the impression that he's completely getting rid of jQuery and stuck on a specific issue. Anyways...